# Identifying an Android device by its hostname

Tags: imei, dhcp

Every Android device in our network has the hostname `android_[some-hex-number].domain.local`. I do have one device which requested 10 IP addresses (different MACs, but always the same hostname). Is there a way to get IMEI or serial number from that hostname?

I found different information about the hostname:

- http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/269827-identifying-androids-and-iphones-in-dhcp:

  > It appears that the name scheme is `Android_<IMEI number>`.
- https://superuser.com/questions/408539/how-to-set-friendly-network-name-of-android-computer

  > it's the VID (Vendor ID Code)

but none of them seems to fit.

PS: MAC addresses are all from "[InPro Comm](http://www.coffer.com/mac_find/?string=000822)". Maybe there's a way to narrow it down from this side?

Comment: AFAIK the hex-number is the ANDROID-ID which is generated randomly when the device is started for the first time (or after a factory reset). Therefore there should not be any relationship to the device, manufacturer or the MAC address.

Answer (score 3):

If `net.hostname` was not preset by device manufacturer during production then Android would use [`ANDROID_ID`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-7.0.0_r14/services/core/java/com/android/server/ConnectivityService.java#656) to generate the unique `android-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` host name:

```
    // setup our unique device name
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(SystemProperties.get("net.hostname"))) {
        String id = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        if (id != null && id.length() > 0) {
            String name = new String("android-").concat(id);
            SystemProperties.set("net.hostname", name);
        }
    }
```